Why fan motor doesn't spin freely after power is applied?
My Breville toaster oven convection fan stopped working.  I took it apart to access the motor and it spins perfectly with no power.  Zero resistance, silent, and takes a good 10 seconds to slow to a stop.  When I turn the power on it seems like it wants to spin but just won't, even if give it a good push it slows to a stop after only a couple of seconds and humms.  The windings don't look burn out.  I would think it's not the capacitor since I can just manually start the spin (taking the place of the job of the capacitor I think).  It seems like the electromagnet is fighting with itself to keep it spinning.
Update:  playing around with it, I noticed the shaft is a little loose and if I use a screwdriver to hold the shaft in the right spot, then it spins fine with electrical power.  So now I'm thinking the bearings may be worn (but then why would it spin so beautifully without power?)

More of an engineering question, but interesting none the less.

This is the Electrical 'Engineering' Stack site, is it not?

Bearings are not electronic components, are they?

@MrGerber But motors are. Which is the concept in question when the title says "fan motor"

@MOSFET Sure. I was just noting why this can be viewed as a general engineering question. It includes mechanical engineering and electrical engineering. I don't think it's irrelevant tho

The loading on the bearings is different when the motor is powered by its own stator than when it is powered by your hand and its own inertia. Holding it in the correct location manually with a screw driver corrects the shaft alignment. Depending on how the bearings' races are worn (the metal tracks inside the bearings where the balls roll), the motor may be at high friction. Also, the part or assembly that holds the bearing may be cracked/broken.

I get all that, but if the race was worn or the assembly cracked, wouldn't that have the same effect when I spin it manually with no electric power supplied?  without power it spins perfect.  It's very smooth and quiet.  And you are correct in the comments above.  My question had nothing to do with the bearings.  It is about a motor and what could be wrong with the motor when electricity is applied.

@MilkyTech The forces you're applying aren't the same forces that the stator is exerting on the rotor. When you are spinning the fan by hand, only the healthy part of the bearings are being utilized. When the stator is trying to spin the rotor, there are axial forces exerted that your not exerting and non-symmetric radial forces due to bifurcation.
